# MySQL sort within one column of data

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

For example, if I had a column in a database called RANDOM that has random bits of information distinguished by their end notation like this:

RANDOM

```
1. 12312 KM, 201 M, 1213 H, 101029 DOLLARS
2. 231 KM, 2351 M, 754 H, 345 DOLLARS, 120 L, 1201 FT
3. 2324 M
```

Some entries have other miscellaneous but important data points while others my only have one or two. 
I would like to sort using only data within column RANDOM.

```
$RESULT = mysqli_query($CON, "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE RANDOM CONTAINS 'M' ORDER BY 'NUMBER BEFORE M'");
```

Therefore this would find the 3 rows that contain 'M' and then sort by the number in front of 'M'. Similarly with other variables like KM or DOLLARS. Is this possible using pure MySQL in a single statement?

Comment: Probably best not to bother with an RDBMS for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question then yes you could do it in one line , just requires some manipulation as your data is all in the one column.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT *, CAST(LEFT(RANDOM, INSTR(RANDOM, '.') - 1) AS UNSIGNED) AS ORD_NUMBER 
     FROM `test_table`
    ) DERIVED_TABLE ORDER BY ORD_NUMBER DESC
```

Basically we are getting the number at the start by using INSTR to find the first . ( assuming this is the format for all items) and then to be safe we cast that as an integer. The data is returned using a derived table so then we sort on our dynamically calculated ord_number that's the result from filtering. Hope that helps.

So using this principle you can filter out however you like :)

But maybe rethink the db Design as doing anykind of query like this means maybe your RDBMS isn't setup correct (simple solution new column with that value :))

Answer (score 0):

Your sort would require a 2 aspirin headache with 
ORDER BY substr('str',locate(str,a,b),locate(str,b,c))